# ORACLE update-set with subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Please help me with the simple `UPDATE-SET` query with `SELECT` subquery

I have tables A and B with columns DATED and ID in each table
I need to set DATED of row in table A with DATED of row of table B based on certain IDs - something like this (simplified example):

```
UPDATE A SET DATED = (SELECT DATED FROM B WHERE ID = yyy) WHERE ID = xxx;
```

`xxx` and `yyy` are constants (numbers)

Oracle returns an error - it cannot understand second WHERE..

Comment: Show the error text, please.

Comment: SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "WHERE ID =..." - rest of line ignored.

Comment: this error belongs to an application?

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement (as it is written here) is correct. The error was lost when you simplified your code before write here. Give please a code with a reproducible error.

Comment: Your sql is correct, i ran the same sql and it works fine for me

Comment: Just re-arranged everything into one string and now it works. Probably some syntax error, sorry..

Comment: The `SP2-0734` error refers to a command beginning "WHERE ID =...". Note `beginning`. Presumably there was a blank line before that and you have `sqlblanklines OFF` (the default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### try this:

```
UPDATE A SET a.DATED = (SELECT b.DATED FROM B WHERE b.ID = yyy) WHERE a.ID = xxx;
```

> use alias